# How can i create intervals over a interval with specific ranges

Tags: java, time, intervals

I want to create an interval of 12 hours, consider this as main interval. Within  this interval only sub intervals should be created. If a subInterval 1 is from 9 AM to 10AM then next sub interval should not be allowed to use interval between 9-10. Then the remaining left interval to be used is from 1AM to 9AM and 10AM to 12AM.

> 1--------------------- 9*****10----------------12

Star mark region should be blocked for using in further intervals. Same ways if new interval is from 8AM to 9AM. Then time interval from 8AM to 10Am should be blocked for further use. I am able to create a single interval but how can i create intervals within interval? And is this the correct approach or i should look for some different DS.

Comment: What have you tried?  Post the code.  What's not working?

Comment: I haven't tried much on this just looking for some data structure to store data in intervals.

Comment: Build your own `Interval` class with two instance variables of type `LocalTime` for start and end of interval.

Comment: can you please elaborate @OleV.V.

Comment: Rather not. I am not here to do your design work for you. :-)